# Codeigniter redirect doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have this login function:

```
public function members() {
  if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
    redirect('pag/index.php');    
 }else{
    redirect('main/restricted');
 }
```

this will get me a 404 if I succes to login! 
But if I will try like this:

```
public function members() {
  if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
    $this->load->view('pag/index.php');    
 }else{
    redirect('main/restricted');
 }
```

With `$this->load->view` it will work, and also the `redirect('main/restricted')` is working. I have problems with `redirect('pag/index.php');` returning me 404.

Thid is how my `.htaccess` is looking:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /delta-rom/
#CI_FOLDER is the Location of your CI files.

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]



</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I'm using Codeigniter 3v. Ty alot for your time.

Comment: Solved, thanks, was another function in conflict!

Comment: PHP is not JavaScript.  In other words, you cannot use the Code Snippets feature for PHP code, and that should have been obvious by the "JavaScript" label on the code pane.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way to redirect in Codeigniter.

```
return redirect('pag');
```

don't use .php extension while redirecting in codeigniter because ultimately you are calling a controller class and its method as per codeigniters URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

general syntax for redirect method id:
**redirect('controller_name/method_name');**

In your code:

```
public function members() {
   if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
      redirect('pag/index.php'); //pag is controller name but index.php is not method name
      //redirect('pag/index');  // try this 
   }else{
      redirect('main/restricted');
}
```

but in view()

```
$this->load->view('pag/index.php'); //index.php is a page located in "applicatoin/view/pag"
```

so this is how redirect and view methods works.
hope u will understand :)